# Sending unescaped JSON data to WCF via POST

Tags: c#, json, wcf, post

I have a restfull WCF Service, which is working fine when I send escaped JSON data through POST method. But It arises error bad request when I send Unescaped JSON. Can anybody tell me a solution. This is the Interface Code that I am using in WCF.

```
  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IService1
  {
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "LoginCloudUser", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    DNNLoginResponse LoginCloudUser(string args);

    [OperationContract]
    UserCredential GetDataUsingDataContract(UserCredential composite);

    // TODO: Add your service operations here
  }
```

Update: I am using JSON.Net to serialize the JSON. But I have tried removing all the codes and return just the arguments back as string. Still it gets error if JSON is not escaped.

```
public DNNLoginResponse LoginCloudUser(string args)
    {
        try
        {
            JsonSerializerSettings jss = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            jss.StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.Default; 
            DNNLogin du = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DNNLogin>(args, jss);
            bool validateresult = DNNLogin.ValidateUser(du); 

            DNNLoginResponse dlogres = new DNNLoginResponse(); 
            dlogres.result  = validateresult;
            dlogres.resulttype = "Success"; 
            dlogres.userid = du.username;

            return dlogres; //JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dlogres, Formatting.None, jss); 
        }
        catch
        { 
            DNNLoginResponse dlogres = new DNNLoginResponse(); 
            dlogres.result = false;
            dlogres.resulttype = "Internal Error";
            dlogres.userid = string.Empty;

            return dlogres;  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Obvious answer is to escape it... But, could you show some data you are trying to serialise so we can see your exact problem?

Comment: Yea, I have updated it now. 
But I tried removing all the codes from my function, still it gets this error..

Answer (score 0):

I have removed JSON.NEt and changed the code to this, its working really well.

```
 [ServiceContract]
 public interface IService1
 {
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "LoginCloudUser", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    DNNLoginResponse LoginCloudUser(DNNLogin args);

    [OperationContract]
    UserCredential GetDataUsingDataContract(UserCredential composite);

    // TODO: Add your service operations here
}
```

And the function code.

```
       public DNNLoginResponse LoginCloudUser(DNNLogin args)
      {
        try
        {

            bool validateresult = DNNLogin.ValidateUser(args); 

            DNNLoginResponse dlogres = new DNNLoginResponse();
            if (validateresult)
            {
                dlogres.result = validateresult;
                dlogres.resulttype =  "Success" ;
                dlogres.userid = args.username;
            }
            else
            {
                dlogres.result = validateresult;
                dlogres.resulttype = "Login Error";
                dlogres.userid = string.Empty;

            }


            return dlogres; //JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dlogres, Formatting.None, jss); 
        }
        catch
        { 
            DNNLoginResponse dlogres = new DNNLoginResponse(); 
            dlogres.result = false;
            dlogres.resulttype = "Internal Error";
            dlogres.userid = string.Empty;

            return dlogres;  
        }
    }
```